# Underline (or otherwise format) all text in custom environment

Tags: environments, tex-core

I'm trying to define a custom environment, in which all text is underlined. I know the `underline` command underlines its input, but I can't figure out how to get it to work seamlessly with my environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myenvironment}{\underline}{}
\begin{document}
Not underlined
\begin{myenvironment}
Only first character is underlined
\end{myenvironment}
\underline{Underlined correctly}
\end{document}
```

How can I apply `underline` (or other commands) to all the text inside the environment?

Using xelatex 2015 if that matters.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Have you considered loading the `ulem` package (with the option `normalem`) and using the command `\uline{...}` to perform underlining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `soulutf8` and `environ`. But, please, think again about underlining.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{soulutf8,environ}

\NewEnviron{myenvironment}{\expandafter\ul\expandafter{\BODY}}

\begin{document}

Not underlined
\begin{myenvironment}
All words are underlined
All words are underlined
All words are underlined
All words are underlined
All words are underlined
\end{myenvironment}

\ul{Underlined correctly}

\end{document}
```

[image]